# fgetc does not identify EOF

Tags: c, types, aix, eof, fgetc

The program below runs fine on various Solaris/Linux flavours, but not on AIX.
However, if I replace `while(c!=EOF)` with `while(c!=0xff)` on AIX it runs completely fine.

Any thoughts? I checked the fgetc man page on AIX, and it should return the EOF constant!

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
char c;
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("a.txt", "r");
     c=fgetc(fp);
     while(c!=EOF)
        {
        c=fgetc(fp);
        printf("%d",c);
        }

  fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems that AIX has chars that are unsigned

Answer (score 17):

The return value of [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) is `int` not `char`. So change

```
char c;
```

to

```
int c;
```