# Comparing unsigned char and EOF

Tags: c, comparison, eof, unsigned-char, fgetc

when the following code is compiled it goes into an infinite loop:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char  ch;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("abc","r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to Open");
        exit(1);
    }
    while((ch = fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
    printf("%c",ch);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\n",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

The gcc Compiler also gives warning on compilation

```
abc.c:13:warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
```

the code runs fine when `unsigned char` is replaced by `char` or `int` as expected i.e. it terminates.
But the code also runs fine for `unsigned int` as well.
as i have i have read in `EOF` is defines as `-1` in `stdio.h` then why does this code fails for unsigned char but runs fine for unsigned int.

Comment: essentially the same as [fgetc does not identify EOF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977223/fgetc-does-not-identify-eof). I think we have this type of question at least once a week.

Comment: See also http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why must the variable used to hold getchar's return value be declared as int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013167/why-must-the-variable-used-to-hold-getchars-return-value-be-declared-as-int)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The golden rule for writing this line is

```
   while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)
```

**`ch` should be `int`** .Your cute trick of making `ch` unsigned fails because `EOF` is a signed int quantity.

Ok, let's now go into the depth......

**Step 1:**

```
ch=fgetc(fp)
```

`fgetc()` returns `-1` (a signed `int`). By the golden rules of C `ch` gets the last octet of bits which is all `1`'s. And hence the value `255`. The byte pattern of `ch` after the execution of

```
ch = fgetc(fp);
```

would thus be

```
11111111
```

**Step 2:**

```
ch != EOF
```

Now `EOF` is a  **signed integer** and `ch` is an **`unsigned char`** ...

Again I refer to the golden rule of C ... the smaller guy **`ch`** is converted to big size **`int`** before comparision so its byte pattern is now

```
00000000000000000000000011111111 = (255)10
```

while `EOF` is

```
11111111111111111111111111111111 = (-1)10
```

There is no way they can be equal.......  Hence the statement to steer the following while-loop

```
while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)
```

will never evaluate to false ...

And hence the infinite loop .

Comment: The Golden Rule is **always match your parentheses**. You are missing a `)` in both examples, it must be `while((ch=fgetc(stdin))!=EOF)`.

Comment: I just made your clear answer look a bit nicer. Still, could you please elaborate on what you want to express you this pattern: `... = (255)10` and `... = (-1)10`?

Comment: @alk This answer was written by the "student me", hence the inconsistency in notations. 
(255)10 denotes 255 in base 10

Answer (score 7):

There are several implicit conversions going on. They aren't really relevant to the specific warning, but I included them in this answer to show what the compiler really does with that expression.

- ch in your example is of type unsigned char.
- EOF is guaranteed to be of type int (C99 7.19.1).

So the expression is equivalent to

```
(unsigned char)ch != (int)EOF
```

The *integer promotion rules* in C will implicitly convert the unsigned char to unsigned int:

```
(unsigned int)ch != (int)EOF
```

Then the balancing rules (aka *the usual arithmetic conversions*) in C will implicitly convert the int to unsigned int, because each operand must have the same type:

```
(unsigned int)ch != (unsigned int)EOF
```

On your compiler EOF is likely -1:

```
(unsigned int)ch != (unsigned int)-1
```

which, assuming 32-bit CPU, is the same as

```
(unsigned int)ch != 0xFFFFFFFFu
```

A character can never have such a high value, hence the warning.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered this problem too. My solution is to use feof().

```
unsigned int xxFunc(){
  FILE *fin;
  unsigned char c;
  fin = fopen("...", "rb");
  if(feof(fin) != 0) return EOF;
  c = fgetc(fin);
  fclose(fin);
...
}
```

And you can define an int variable to compare with EOF. For example:

```
int flag = xxFunc();
while(flag != EOF) {...}
```

This works for me.

***IMPORTANT UPDATE**********

After using the method I mentioned before, I found a serious problem. 
feof() is not a good way to break the while loop.
Here is the reason for it. http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-58.html

So I find a better way to do this. I use an int variable to do it. here:

```
int flag;
unsigned char c;
while((flag = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) 
{ 
  //so, you are using flag to receive, but transfer the value to c later.
  c = flag;
  ... 
}
```

After my test, this works.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use an int

fgetc() returns an int specifically so that it can indicate the end of file

it runs fine with signed char because EOF (-1) is in the range, but it would break if you read in a char with value greater than 127.

Use an int, cast it to a char after you've checked for EOF

Comment: i know int should be used in proper code but i want to know why unsigned char don't work but unsigned int works...

Comment: how -1 is in range of unsigned int

Comment: Read up on the integer promotion rules.

Answer (score 1):

When you compare an unsigned int with a signed int, it converts the signed int to unsigned int and compares them. Hence when you are reading the file with an unsigned int 'ch', reading an EOF gives you 2^32+1 (on a 4 byte int machine) and when comparing it with EOF, it converts EOF to unsigned which is also 2^32+1 and hence the program stops!

If you use unsigned char ch, when you read the file, reading EOF returns 2^32+1, and this will be casted to unsigned char, which truncates the value to first 8 bits  (on a 1 byte char machine) and gives you an output of 255. Hence you are comparing 255 and 2^32+1, causing an infinite loop.

The problem here is truncating before compare.

If you use

```
while((ch = fgetc(fp))!=(unsigned char)EOF)
    printf("%c",ch);
```

you program will run fine!

Answer (score 0):

a lint warning is produced with this kind of implementation

> Comparing type 'char' with EOF

```
 // read the data in a buffer
611     ch = getc(csv_file);
612     while (ch != EOF)
```

FIX:

```
// read the data in a buffer
    while ((ch = getc(csv_file)) != EOF)
```