# EOF does not work in Mac Xcode (C)?

Tags: c

I am currently running this character counting .c but the EOF is not reached unless I press control D, which is very annoying.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main () {

   long nc;

   nc = 0;

   while (getchar() != EOF) {
       ++nc;
   }

   printf("%ld\n", nc);

}
```

Comment: don't you mean EOL? (End Of Line) and not End Of File

Comment: Any would you expect EOF unless CTRL+D?

Comment: `main ()` --> `int main (void)`

Comment: @SouravGhosh `int main(int argc, char **argv)` if you want to get picky about it.

Comment: @DaanTimmer: EOF is right, see manpage: `reads  the  next  character from stream and returns it as an unsigned char cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error.`

Comment: @duskwuff Edited. :)

Comment: @duskwuff: There's no need to use the argc/argv form for `main()` when the program ignores the command line arguments.  Both `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char **argv)` are explicitly OK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler At the time I replied, SouravGhosh's comment was recommending `int main()`, with no argument list.

Comment: @duskwuff: I'm not sure I understand. It probably doesn't matter. I'll clean up my comments later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is the expected behavior.

EOF is encountered **only** when the input stream ends. What you are doing (I suppose) is press the enter key. That doesn't signal EOF, because you could type in more stuff after the enter. Ctr+D signals the end of a file.

What you can do is look for End Of Line. 
And you also need to look for EOF since the user can terminate by pressing Ctr+D
(as suggested by @DavidC.Rankin)

This can be done by matching getchar() with `'\n'` and EOF as

```
int c
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    ++nc;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What happens if the user presses `Ctrl+d` (or `ctrl+z` on windoze)? (you need to check both `'\n'` && `EOF`) (e.g. `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) ...`)

Comment: @DavidC.Ranakin, oh yes. I will fix it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: You have to check both like this: `char readChar;
   while ((readChar = getchar()) != EOF && readChar != '\n') { ... }`

Comment: Only if your implementation defines `EOF` as type `char`, otherwise `EOF` (`-1` generally) will never be seen on a little-endian box.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, corrected! Also is that fancy spelling for "windoze" intentional? :p

Comment: (tongue-in-cheek) yep, it's just a light-hearted dig at the windows crowd. (I don't have anything against any OS, but do prefer not to rent software...)

Comment: @AndreKampling See: See: [**Comparing unsigned char and EOF**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586722/comparing-unsigned-char-and-eof) for an explanation of why it should be `int` . (because `getchar` reads each char as an `unsigned char` cast to an `int` which would result in the comparison of `if (0x000000ff == 0xffffffff)` in your case)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Thank you for your hint!