# Segmentation fault when trying to read file (C)

Tags: c, file, command-line, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a program in C where the program will go through the file char by char and print them out to the console. However, when running the code below, I get the error `Segmentation fault: 11`. Where is the issue in my code?

```
void readFile(char fileName);

int main(const int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        readFile(*argv[i]);
    }

    exit(status);
}

void readFile(char fileName)
{
    FILE* file;
    char c;

    file = fopen(&fileName, "r");

    do {
        c = getc(file);
        printf("%c", c);
        if (!isalpha(c)) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    } while (c != EOF);

    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: A debugger will tell you which line segfaults.

Comment: Your `readFile` logic is wrong: You're using `c` before checking whether it's `EOF`, and `c` has the wrong type (it needs to be `int`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of your `readFile` is wrong.

```
void readFile(char fileName);
```

`readFile` is function that expects a single character, not a string. `*argv[i]`
returns the first letter of the string pointed to by `argv[i]`.

```
void readFile(const char *fileName)
{
    FILE* file;
    int c; // getc returns an int

    file = fopen(fileName, "r");

    // always check for errors
    if(file == NULL)
        return;

    do {
        c = getc(file);
        printf("%c", c);
        if (!isalpha(c)) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    } while (c != EOF);

    fclose(file); // do not forget to close your streams.
}
```

Note here that your `do-while`-loop is wrong, because you should check **first**
whether `c` is `EOF`. If it isn't then you can print it. It should be:

```
while((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
{
    putc(c, stdout); // equivalent to printf("%c", c)
    if(!isalpha(c))
        puts("");  // equivalent to printf("\n");
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
int main(const int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        readFile(argv[i]);
    }

    exit(status);
}
```

Also note that `getc` returns a `int`, not a `char`, so the `c` variable must be
an `int`.

> *man fgets*
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int getc(FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> `getc()` is equivalent to `fgetc()` except that it may be implemented as a macro which evaluates stream more than once.
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> `fgetc()`, `getc()` and `getchar()` return the character **read as an `unsigned char` cast to an `int`** or `EOF` on end of file or error.

See also [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8586867/1480131)

Comment: The do-while loop should be a while loop (check for `EOF` before printing `c`).

Comment: I have `#include <ctype.h>`, which I believe addresses the int issue.

Comment: @melpomene I added the `fclose`, I missed that.

Comment: Usually the failure mode for `char c` is reversed: Character 255 gets mistaken for `EOF` (because `char` is often a signed type).

Comment: @melpomene I added a note about the do-while loop, thanks for the feedback. About the `EOF` check with `char`: is it `EOF` that get promoted to a `signed char`?

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it wrong in many level. You passed the `0`th character of the `i-th` argument. You want to pass the whole string. You need to pass `char*`.

```
readFile(argv[i]);
```

You will pass this `char*` directly to `fopen` and then check it's return value. Looping could be as simple as

```
while( (c=getc(file)) != EOF){

}
...
fclose(file);
```

And you have to use `int c` instead of `char c` ensuring that it can hold all the values returned by `getc`.