# How do I get number of characters in each line?

Tags: c, file

I need to get number of characters in each line and then paste it into another file (school project) but even my prototype is already not working.

I have already trying continuing seeing whether problem resolves itself when I paste it into another file but it didn't work so I'm back to this.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fw;
    FILE *fr;
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    fr = fopen("vstup.txt","r");
    fw = fopen("vystup.txt","w");
    while ((c = getc(fr)) != EOF)
    {
        while ((c = getc(fr)) != '\n')
        {
            i++;
        }
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? By the way, you are skipping the first character in each line.

Comment: You don't zero out the counter...

Comment: `char c` should be `int c`.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8586722/9232218) and the link in the comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing unsigned char and EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586722/comparing-unsigned-char-and-eof)

Comment: @Yastanub That's the least of the problems.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  When asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: At a minimum, the posted code is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Are you expecting us to guess as to what header files your code is actually including?

Comment: OT: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "my error message" )` to output both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the problem occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: Please read/understand the MAN page for the functions that you use.  For instance, the function: `getc()` actually returns a `int`, not a `char` and EOF is a `int`

Comment: the posted code, at best, counts the number of characters (except the newline sequences) in a file and displays that count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c` has to be declared `int`, not `char`. `EOF` might not be a valid `char` value, so the inequality might succeed forever.

You shouldn't call `getc()` twice. You never check the result of the first call to see if it's a newline.

You need to set `i` back to `0` after you read a newline, otherwise you'll keep adding the next line's length to the previous line.

You should only print the length when you read a newline, not every time through the loop. And if the last line doesn't end with newline, you should print its length after the loop; you can tell this happened if `i` is not `0` when it's done.

Since the lengths should be written into the other file, you should use `fprintf()`.

```
while ((c=getc(fr)) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\n') {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        i = 0;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
if (i != 0) {
    fprintf(fw, "%d\n", i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a nested loop. You need to zero out the counter either way, so you may as well just use an `if` instead of a while:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fw, *fr;
    int count = 0;
    int c;

    fr = fopen("vstup.txt","r");
    fw = fopen("vystup.txt","w");

    while ((c = getc(fr)) != EOF) {
        count++;
        if(c == '\n') {
            fprintf(fw, "%d\n", count);
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    fclose(fr);
    fclose(fw);
}
```

This version will count newlines as valid characters.

Note that `c` must be an `int`, not a `char`, so that it can hold every character value returned by `getc` as well as `EOF`, which is not a character value.

And don't forget to close your files!

Comment: @Eric. That is indeed much better, so I've shamelessly stolen your suggestion.

Comment: It is not stolen; it was offered freely. I get more done by teaching other people to improve answers than by writing everything myself.

Comment: @Eric. Thank you. I feel the same way most days.