# EOF missing for unix file

Tags: c, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [fgetc does not identify EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977223/fgetc-does-not-identify-eof)
>   [fgetc, checking EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057259/fgetc-checking-eof)

I have created a file and named it "file.txt" in Unix. I tried to read the file content from my C program. I am not able to receive the EOF character. Unix doesn't store EOF character on file creation? If so what is the alternative way to read the EOF from a Unix created file using C.

Here's the code sample

```
int main(){
File *fp;
int nl,c;
nl =0;
fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
  if (c=='\n')
    nl++;
}
return 0; 
}
```

If I explicitly give <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> the EOF is detected even when I use `char c`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fgetc does not identify EOF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977223/fgetc-does-not-identify-eof), see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057259/fgetc-checking-eof and many, many others

Comment: Also note: EOF is not "stored in files", it's just a way for I/O functions to tell you they reached the end of a file. There isn't a magic byte stored at the end.

Comment: Note that it should be `FILE *fp;` and not `File *fp;`, and you should also check that the file was opened successfully before reading anything via the variable `fp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen if the type of `c` is `char` (and `char` is unsigned in your compiler, you can check this by examining the value of `CHAR_MIN` in ) and not `int`.

The value of `EOF` is negative according to the C standard.

So, implicitly casting `EOF` to `unsigned char` will lose the true value of `EOF` and the comparison will always fail.

**UPDATE**: There's a bigger problem that has to be addressed first. In the expression `c = fgetc(fp) != EOF`, `fgetc(fp) != EOF` is evaluated first (to 0 or 1) and then the value is assigned to `c`. If there's at least one character in the file, `fgetc(fp) != EOF` will evaluate to 0 and the body of the `while` loop will never execute. You need to add parentheses, like so: `(c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF`.

Answer (score 3):

Missing parentheses. Should be:

```
while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
```

Comment: This prevents the code compiling - but doesn't explain a run-time error.  It also tells us that the code in the question is not the code that was compiled, which always makes the debugging harder.

Comment: How would that prevent the code from compiling? Assigning the value of the result of the inequality operator to a scalar variable is perfectly valid C.

Answer (score 1):

Remember: `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  It has to return an `int` because its set of return values includes all possible valid characters plus a separate (negative) EOF indicator.

There are two possible traps if you use type `char` for `c` instead of `int`:

1. If the type `char` is signed with your compiler, you will detect a valid character as EOF.  Often, the character ÿ (y-umlaut, officially known in Unicode as LATIN LOWER CASE Y WITH DIAERESIS, U+00FF, hex code 0xFF in the ISO 8859-1 aka Latin 1 code set) will be detected as equivalent to EOF, when it is a valid character.
2. If the type `char` is unsigned, then the comparison will never be true.

Both problems are serious, and both are avoided by using the correct type:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if (fp != 0)
{
    int c;
    int nl = 0;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        if (c == '\n')
            nl++;
    printf("Number of lines: %d\n", nl);
}
```

Note that the type is `FILE` and not `File`.  Note that you should check that the file was opened before trying to read via `fp`.

---

> If I explicitly give CTRL + D, the EOF is detected even when I use `char c`.

This means that your compiler provides you with `char` as a signed type.  It also means you will not be able to count lines accurately in files which contain ÿ.

---

Unlike CP/M and DOS, Unix does not use any character to indicate EOF; you reach EOF when there are no more characters to read.  What confuses many people is that if you type a certain key combination at the terminal, programs detect EOF.  What actually happens is that the terminal driver recognizes the character and sends any unread characters to the program.  If there are no unread characters, the program gets 0 bytes returned, which is the same result you get when you've reached the end of file.  So, the character combination (often, but not always, <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>) appears to 'send EOF' to the program.  However, the character is not stored in a file if you are using `cat >file`; further, if you read a file which contains a control-D, that is a perfectly fine character with byte value 0x04.  If a program generates a control-D and sends that to a program, that does not indicate EOF to the program.  It is strictly a property of Unix terminals (tty and pty — teletype and pseudo-teletype — devices).

Answer (score 0):

You do not show how you declare the variable `c` it should be of type `int`, not `char`.