# Having problems Reading a file in C

Tags: c

I am trying to solve a problem which requires me to read a file and generate another file which has the same contents as the original but every fourth byte removed.I tried it doing this way ...

```
int main()
{
  FILE *p;
  FILE *q;
  int i=0,k=0;
  char c;

  p = fopen("C:\\Users\\Teja\\Desktop\\Beethoven.raw","rw");
  q = fopen("C:\\Users\\Teja\\Desktop\\Beethoven_new.raw","w+");

  printf("%x is the EOF character \n",EOF);
  while((c=fgetc(p))!=EOF)
  {

     if(i==3){
      i=0;
      printf("Removing %x %d \n",c,k++);
     }
     else{
      printf("Putting %x %d \n",c,k++);
      fputc(c,q);
      i++;
     }
  }
  fclose(p);
  fclose(q);

  return 0;
}
```

The file that i was trying to read is a .raw file and it is around 10-15 MB. I notice that the above code stops reading the file after typically 88 bytes. Is there any way to read large files or am i doing anything wrong ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977223/fgetc-does-not-identify-eof - getc and friends return **int**, not char.

Comment: Do you have a shareware compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what has already been pointed out, a note on opening files: It sounds like your file in a binary file, which means you must add a `b` to the mode string. Additionally, `rw` is not a mode, since you only read from `p` you want `rb`, and since you only write to `q` you want `wb` or `wb+`.

By the way, the reason why you need `fgetc` to return an int is because `fgetc` must return 257 unique values: all the possible values of `char`, that is `0x00` thru `0xFF` as well as something unique to signify EOF, usually `-1`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
char c;
```

to

```
int c;
```

as the return type of [fetgetc()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgetc/) is an `int` and not `char`.