# Scanning binary files for a virus signature

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to scan for a virus signature in a binary file (without using strstr()), and printing if the signature was found or not. But the code doesn't work. I read the files outside of the function.

Unfortunately the code doesn't work, even when I'm trying to scan the virus signature itself.

```
int searchForSignature(FILE* file_to_search, FILE* virus) {
    int v_size = 0;
    int f_size = 0;


    fseek(virus, 0L, SEEK_END);
    v_size = ftell(virus);
    fseek(virus, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fseek(file_to_search, 0L, SEEK_END);
    f_size = ftell(file_to_search);
    fseek(file_to_search, 0, SEEK_SET);

    printf("VIRUS SIZE: %d FILE SIZE: %d\n", v_size, f_size);

    if (v_size > f_size)
    {
        printf("VIRUS NOT FOUND\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int counter = 0;  char ch = ' '; char ch2 = ' ';
    while ((ch = (char)fgetc(file_to_search)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%d\n", counter);
        if (counter == v_size)
        {
            printf("VIRUS FOUND\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ch2 = (char)fgetc(virus);
            if (ch == ch2)
            {
                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("VIRUS NOT FOUND\n");
    return 1;
}
```

how I read the files outside of the function:

```
FILE* virus_file = NULL;
virus_file = fopen("example file path", "rb");
if (virus_file == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file");
    return 1;
}

FILE* file_to_scan = NULL;
file_to_scan = fopen("example file path 2", "rb");
if (file_to_scan == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more precise as to what "doesn't work" about this code?

Comment: And how about a [mre]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fgetc does not identify EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977223/fgetc-does-not-identify-eof)

Comment: Note that `fgetc` returns an `int` because `EOF` is -1. When you cast the result to a `char`, then a _legit_ data byte of 0xFF will mimic [an early] EOF. Remove the `(char)` cast and use `int ch;` Casting the return value of `fgetc` to `char` actually makes the code run _slower_ on some/most CPUs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least these problems:

**Success too late**

`counter == v_size` may be true right after `counter++;`.  There may not exist another character in the file for the next loop's `if (counter == v_size)`.  Instead test `counter == v_size` right after incrementing.

**No reset**

If only a partial match is found, match testing should not resume on the next source file character, but back up to the beginning of the compare, then advance 1.

Consider:

```
search file: "aaac"
virus:       "aac"
```

Searching *search file* fails on "aa(a)..." (the 3rd 'a'), yet needs to resume on "a(a)" (the 2nd 'a').

Virus file needs to `rewind()` on failed match.  I recommend to read the entire virus signature into allocated memory (e.g.: `unsigned char *virus = malloc(v_size);` rather than re-reading from a file.

**Loss of information**

`int fgetc()` returns 257 different values: 0-255 and `EOF`.  Saving that result in a `char` loses information.  Use `int ch = fgetc(...)`, `int ch2 = fgetc(...)`.

This can explain OP's "code doesnt working, even when Im trying to scan the virus signature itself." as one of the virus bytes is wrongly matches `EOF` when converted to `char`.

Casts are not needed to solve this.

**Wrong type length**

`ftell(virus)` returns a `long`.  Saving the result in an `int` can lose information.  Also code lacks error checks here.

**Unneeded code**

`if (v_size > f_size)` block is not needed.

---

Alternative

```
// Pseudo code
Read virus into an allocated buffer.
Read a chunk of test file into a test buffer at least 2x virus size.
Walk test buffer (1 char at a time) trying `memcmp()`. 
  Stop if match found,
  until remaining test buffer not full enough for a possible match.
Move remaining test buffer to start and re-fill as able.
If not able to re-fill at all, we are done - no match.
```

This is O(test_size * virus_size).  A more sophisticated "walk" is O(test_size + virus_size).

Comment: I believe `v_size > f_size` is meant to be a shortcut - if the virus is larger than the file, the file can't contain it.  It might not be strictly necessary, but avoids byte comparisons when it can only fail.

Comment: @Dave Meehan, Agreed as to why OP did it, yet is remains not useful. It costs a `fseek(file_to_search, 0L, SEEK_END);` which may be quite expensive.